# In Jupyter Notebook NameError when I try to import a module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, nameerror

I have 2 modules written in Jupyter Notebook (windows OS). I try to import module_1.py into module_2.py like that:

```
import module_2
...
```

I have error:
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
          1 from tkinter import *
          2 
    ----> 3 import Backend
          4 
          5 def view_command():

```
C:\python\GUI\Backend.py in <module>()
     72   {
     73    "cell_type": "code",
---> 74    "execution_count": null,
     75    "metadata": {},
     76    "outputs": [],

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Maybe it is because of in IPython importing is not as simple as in Python.
Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure the python versions are the same?

Comment: Are the modules installed globally? jupyter-notebook will only search there.

Comment: This occurs if you create a Notebook and then rename it to a PY file. If you open that file, the source Python code will wrapped with curly braces, double quotes, with the first several lines containing the erroneous `null` reference. You can actually import this as-is, but you have to stop and restart the kernel for the notebook doing the `import` statements FIRST. Best to clean up that code back to pure Python, and better still to just create a blank PY file and drop your cell code in directly instead of renaming the IPYNB files.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses `None` for null objects. Try to change the null on line 74 to None and import again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem is, line 74 is not my code, it was generated when I tried to execute the code. My code only has 66 lines. Do you have any ideas for that?